# VirtualBox: "Kernel driver not installed" on Kernel 5.15.0

Tags: kernel, virtualbox

I post here what I wrote, with no yet luck, to the VirtualBox forum at https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=104377&p=508627#p508627 .

I installed the newest kernel 5.15.0 on my Linux Mint 19.3 (Ubuntu 18,04) equipped with the latest VirtualBox release.

Starting any VM I get this error:

```
Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver is either not loaded or not set up correctly. Please try setting it up again by executing

'/sbin/vboxconfig'

as root.

If your system has EFI Secure Boot enabled you may also need to sign the kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.

where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.
```

So I ran `/sbin/vboxconfig`:

```
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
vboxdrv.sh: failed: Look at /var/log/vbox-setup.log to find out what went wrong.

There were problems setting up VirtualBox. To re-start the set-up process, run
/sbin/vboxconfig
as root. If your system is using EFI Secure Boot you may need to sign the
kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load
them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.
```

The log file contains:

```
Error building the module:
make V=1 CONFIG_MODULE_SIG= CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_ALL= -C /lib/modules/5.15.0-051500-generic/build M=/tmp/vbox.0 SRCROOT=/tmp/vbox.0 -j8 modules
make[1]: warning: -jN forced in submake: disabling jobserver mode.
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
The kernel was built by: gcc (Ubuntu 11.2.0-7ubuntu2) 11.2.0
You are using: gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=/tmp/vbox.0 \
single-build= \
need-builtin=1 need-modorder=1
gcc -Wp,-MMD,/tmp/vbox.0/linux/.SUPDrv-linux.o.d -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -I./arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -I./include/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/compiler-version.h -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -include ./include/linux/compiler_types.h -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Werror=strict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fshort-wchar -fno-PIE -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=implicit-int -Werror=return-type -Wno-format-security -std=gnu89 -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -m64 -falign-jumps=1 -falign-loops=1 -mno-80387 -mno-fp-ret-in-387 -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mskip-rax-setup -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -DCONFIG_X86_X32_ABI -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mindirect-branch=thunk-extern -mindirect-branch-register -fno-jump-tables -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Wno-frame-address -Wno-format-truncation -Wno-format-overflow -O2 --param=allow-store-data-races=0 -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -fstack-protector-strong -Wimplicit-fallthrough=5 -Wno-main -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-unused-const-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -g -gdwarf-4 -pg -mrecord-mcount -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wvla -Wno-pointer-sign -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-stringop-overflow -Wno-restrict -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -fno-strict-overflow -fno-stack-check -fconserve-stack -Werror=date-time -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types -Werror=designated-init -include /tmp/vbox.0/include/VBox/SUPDrvMangling.h -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-pie -Wno-declaration-after-statement -I./include -I/tmp/vbox.0/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DRT_WITHOUT_PRAGMA_ONCE -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_SUP_R0 -DVBOX -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBOX_WITH_HARDENING -DSUPDRV_WITH_RELEASE_LOGGER -DVBOX_WITHOUT_EFLAGS_AC_SET_IN_VBOXDRV -DIPRT_WITHOUT_EFLAGS_AC_PRESERVING -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS -DCONFIG_VBOXDRV_AS_MISC -DRT_ARCH_AMD64 -fsanitize=bounds -fsanitize-undefined-trap-on-error -DMODULE -DKBUILD_BASENAME='"SUPDrv_linux"' -DKBUILD_MODNAME='"vboxdrv"' -D__KBUILD_MODNAME=kmod_vboxdrv -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o /tmp/vbox.0/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c
gcc -Wp,-MMD,/tmp/vbox.0/.SUPDrv.o.d -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -I./arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -I./include/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/compiler-version.h -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -include ./include/linux/compiler_types.h -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Werror=strict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fshort-wchar -fno-PIE -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=implicit-int -Werror=return-type -Wno-format-security -std=gnu89 -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -m64 -falign-jumps=1 -falign-loops=1 -mno-80387 -mno-fp-ret-in-387 -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mskip-rax-setup -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -DCONFIG_X86_X32_ABI -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mindirect-branch=thunk-extern -mindirect-branch-register -fno-jump-tables -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Wno-frame-address -Wno-format-truncation -Wno-format-overflow -O2 --param=allow-store-data-races=0 -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -fstack-protector-strong -Wimplicit-fallthrough=5 -Wno-main -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-unused-const-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -g -gdwarf-4 -pg -mrecord-mcount -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wvla -Wno-pointer-sign -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-stringop-overflow -Wno-restrict -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -fno-strict-overflow -fno-stack-check -fconserve-stack -Werror=date-time -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types -Werror=designated-init -include /tmp/vbox.0/include/VBox/SUPDrvMangling.h -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-pie -Wno-declaration-after-statement -I./include -I/tmp/vbox.0/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DRT_WITHOUT_PRAGMA_ONCE -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_SUP_R0 -DVBOX -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBOX_WITH_HARDENING -DSUPDRV_WITH_RELEASE_LOGGER -DVBOX_WITHOUT_EFLAGS_AC_SET_IN_VBOXDRV -DIPRT_WITHOUT_EFLAGS_AC_PRESERVING -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS -DCONFIG_VBOXDRV_AS_MISC -DRT_ARCH_AMD64 -fsanitize=bounds -fsanitize-undefined-trap-on-error -DMODULE -DKBUILD_BASENAME='"SUPDrv"' -DKBUILD_MODNAME='"vboxdrv"' -D__KBUILD_MODNAME=kmod_vboxdrv -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrv.o /tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrv.c
gcc -Wp,-MMD,/tmp/vbox.0/.SUPDrvGip.o.d -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -I./arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -I./include/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/compiler-version.h -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -include ./include/linux/compiler_types.h -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Werror=strict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fshort-wchar -fno-PIE -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=implicit-int -Werror=return-type -Wno-format-security -std=gnu89 -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -m64 -falign-jumps=1 -falign-loops=1 -mno-80387 -mno-fp-ret-in-387 -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mskip-rax-setup -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -DCONFIG_X86_X32_ABI -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mindirect-branch=thunk-extern -mindirect-branch-register -fno-jump-tables -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Wno-frame-address -Wno-format-truncation -Wno-format-overflow -O2 --param=allow-store-data-races=0 -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -fstack-protector-strong -Wimplicit-fallthrough=5 -Wno-main -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-unused-const-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -g -gdwarf-4 -pg -mrecord-mcount -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wvla -Wno-pointer-sign -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-stringop-overflow -Wno-restrict -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -fno-strict-overflow -fno-stack-check -fconserve-stack -Werror=date-time -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types -Werror=designated-init -include /tmp/vbox.0/include/VBox/SUPDrvMangling.h -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-pie -Wno-declaration-after-statement -I./include -I/tmp/vbox.0/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DRT_WITHOUT_PRAGMA_ONCE -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_SUP_R0 -DVBOX -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBOX_WITH_HARDENING -DSUPDRV_WITH_RELEASE_LOGGER -DVBOX_WITHOUT_EFLAGS_AC_SET_IN_VBOXDRV -DIPRT_WITHOUT_EFLAGS_AC_PRESERVING -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS -DCONFIG_VBOXDRV_AS_MISC -DRT_ARCH_AMD64 -fsanitize=bounds -fsanitize-undefined-trap-on-error -DMODULE -DKBUILD_BASENAME='"SUPDrvGip"' -DKBUILD_MODNAME='"vboxdrv"' -D__KBUILD_MODNAME=kmod_vboxdrv -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrvGip.o /tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrvGip.c
gcc -Wp,-MMD,/tmp/vbox.0/.SUPDrvSem.o.d -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -I./arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -I./include/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/compiler-version.h -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -include ./include/linux/compiler_types.h -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Werror=strict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fshort-wchar -fno-PIE -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=implicit-int -Werror=return-type -Wno-format-security -std=gnu89 -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -m64 -falign-jumps=1 -falign-loops=1 -mno-80387 -mno-fp-ret-in-387 -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mskip-rax-setup -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -DCONFIG_X86_X32_ABI -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mindirect-branch=thunk-extern -mindirect-branch-register -fno-jump-tables -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Wno-frame-address -Wno-format-truncation -Wno-format-overflow -O2 --param=allow-store-data-races=0 -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -fstack-protector-strong -Wimplicit-fallthrough=5 -Wno-main -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-unused-const-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -g -gdwarf-4 -pg -mrecord-mcount -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wvla -Wno-pointer-sign -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-stringop-overflow -Wno-restrict -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -fno-strict-overflow -fno-stack-check -fconserve-stack -Werror=date-time -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types -Werror=designated-init -include /tmp/vbox.0/include/VBox/SUPDrvMangling.h -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-pie -Wno-declaration-after-statement -I./include -I/tmp/vbox.0/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DRT_WITHOUT_PRAGMA_ONCE -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_SUP_R0 -DVBOX -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBOX_WITH_HARDENING -DSUPDRV_WITH_RELEASE_LOGGER -DVBOX_WITHOUT_EFLAGS_AC_SET_IN_VBOXDRV -DIPRT_WITHOUT_EFLAGS_AC_PRESERVING -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS -DCONFIG_VBOXDRV_AS_MISC -DRT_ARCH_AMD64 -fsanitize=bounds -fsanitize-undefined-trap-on-error -DMODULE -DKBUILD_BASENAME='"SUPDrvSem"' -DKBUILD_MODNAME='"vboxdrv"' -D__KBUILD_MODNAME=kmod_vboxdrv -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrvSem.o /tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrvSem.c
gcc -Wp,-MMD,/tmp/vbox.0/.SUPDrvTracer.o.d -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -I./arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -I./include/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/compiler-version.h -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -include ./include/linux/compiler_types.h -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Werror=strict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fshort-wchar -fno-PIE -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=implicit-int -Werror=return-type -Wno-format-security -std=gnu89 -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -m64 -falign-jumps=1 -falign-loops=1 -mno-80387 -mno-fp-ret-in-387 -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mskip-rax-setup -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -DCONFIG_X86_X32_ABI -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mindirect-branch=thunk-extern -mindirect-branch-register -fno-jump-tables -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Wno-frame-address -Wno-format-truncation -Wno-format-overflow -O2 --param=allow-store-data-races=0 -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -fstack-protector-strong -Wimplicit-fallthrough=5 -Wno-main -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-unused-const-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -g -gdwarf-4 -pg -mrecord-mcount -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wvla -Wno-pointer-sign -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-stringop-overflow -Wno-restrict -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -fno-strict-overflow -fno-stack-check -fconserve-stack -Werror=date-time -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types -Werror=designated-init -include /tmp/vbox.0/include/VBox/SUPDrvMangling.h -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-pie -Wno-declaration-after-statement -I./include -I/tmp/vbox.0/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DRT_WITHOUT_PRAGMA_ONCE -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_SUP_R0 -DVBOX -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBOX_WITH_HARDENING -DSUPDRV_WITH_RELEASE_LOGGER -DVBOX_WITHOUT_EFLAGS_AC_SET_IN_VBOXDRV -DIPRT_WITHOUT_EFLAGS_AC_PRESERVING -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS -DCONFIG_VBOXDRV_AS_MISC -DRT_ARCH_AMD64 -fsanitize=bounds -fsanitize-undefined-trap-on-error -DMODULE -DKBUILD_BASENAME='"SUPDrvTracer"' -DKBUILD_MODNAME='"vboxdrv"' -D__KBUILD_MODNAME=kmod_vboxdrv -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrvTracer.o /tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrvTracer.c
gcc -Wp,-MMD,/tmp/vbox.0/.SUPLibAll.o.d -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -I./arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -I./include/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/compiler-version.h -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -include ./include/linux/compiler_types.h -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Werror=strict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fshort-wchar -fno-PIE -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=implicit-int -Werror=return-type -Wno-format-security -std=gnu89 -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -m64 -falign-jumps=1 -falign-loops=1 -mno-80387 -mno-fp-ret-in-387 -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mskip-rax-setup -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -DCONFIG_X86_X32_ABI -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mindirect-branch=thunk-extern -mindirect-branch-register -fno-jump-tables -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Wno-frame-address -Wno-format-truncation -Wno-format-overflow -O2 --param=allow-store-data-races=0 -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -fstack-protector-strong -Wimplicit-fallthrough=5 -Wno-main -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-unused-const-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -g -gdwarf-4 -pg -mrecord-mcount -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wvla -Wno-pointer-sign -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-stringop-overflow -Wno-restrict -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -fno-strict-overflow -fno-stack-check -fconserve-stack -Werror=date-time -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types -Werror=designated-init -include /tmp/vbox.0/include/VBox/SUPDrvMangling.h -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-pie -Wno-declaration-after-statement -I./include -I/tmp/vbox.0/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DRT_WITHOUT_PRAGMA_ONCE -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_SUP_R0 -DVBOX -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBOX_WITH_HARDENING -DSUPDRV_WITH_RELEASE_LOGGER -DVBOX_WITHOUT_EFLAGS_AC_SET_IN_VBOXDRV -DIPRT_WITHOUT_EFLAGS_AC_PRESERVING -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS -DCONFIG_VBOXDRV_AS_MISC -DRT_ARCH_AMD64 -fsanitize=bounds -fsanitize-undefined-trap-on-error -DMODULE -DKBUILD_BASENAME='"SUPLibAll"' -DKBUILD_MODNAME='"vboxdrv"' -D__KBUILD_MODNAME=kmod_vboxdrv -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/SUPLibAll.o /tmp/vbox.0/SUPLibAll.c
gcc -Wp,-MMD,/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/.initterm-r0drv.o.d -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -I./arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -I./include/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/compiler-version.h -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -include ./include/linux/compiler_types.h -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Werror=strict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fshort-wchar -fno-PIE -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=implicit-int -Werror=return-type -Wno-format-security -std=gnu89 -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -m64 -falign-jumps=1 -falign-loops=1 -mno-80387 -mno-fp-ret-in-387 -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mskip-rax-setup -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -DCONFIG_X86_X32_ABI -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mindirect-branch=thunk-extern -mindirect-branch-register -fno-jump-tables -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Wno-frame-address -Wno-format-truncation -Wno-format-overflow -O2 --param=allow-store-data-races=0 -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -fstack-protector-strong -Wimplicit-fallthrough=5 -Wno-main -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-unused-const-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -g -gdwarf-4 -pg -mrecord-mcount -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wvla -Wno-pointer-sign -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-stringop-overflow -Wno-restrict -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -fno-strict-overflow -fno-stack-check -fconserve-stack -Werror=date-time -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types -Werror=designated-init -include /tmp/vbox.0/include/VBox/SUPDrvMangling.h -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-pie -Wno-declaration-after-statement -I./include -I/tmp/vbox.0/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DRT_WITHOUT_PRAGMA_ONCE -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_SUP_R0 -DVBOX -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBOX_WITH_HARDENING -DSUPDRV_WITH_RELEASE_LOGGER -DVBOX_WITHOUT_EFLAGS_AC_SET_IN_VBOXDRV -DIPRT_WITHOUT_EFLAGS_AC_PRESERVING -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS -DCONFIG_VBOXDRV_AS_MISC -DRT_ARCH_AMD64 -fsanitize=bounds -fsanitize-undefined-trap-on-error -DMODULE -DKBUILD_BASENAME='"initterm_r0drv"' -DKBUILD_MODNAME='"vboxdrv"' -D__KBUILD_MODNAME=kmod_vboxdrv -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/initterm-r0drv.o /tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/initterm-r0drv.c
gcc -Wp,-MMD,/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/.alloc-r0drv.o.d -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -I./arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -I./include/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/compiler-version.h -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -include ./include/linux/compiler_types.h -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Werror=strict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fshort-wchar -fno-PIE -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=implicit-int -Werror=return-type -Wno-format-security -std=gnu89 -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -m64 -falign-jumps=1 -falign-loops=1 -mno-80387 -mno-fp-ret-in-387 -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mskip-rax-setup -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -DCONFIG_X86_X32_ABI -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mindirect-branch=thunk-extern -mindirect-branch-register -fno-jump-tables -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Wno-frame-address -Wno-format-truncation -Wno-format-overflow -O2 --param=allow-store-data-races=0 -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -fstack-protector-strong -Wimplicit-fallthrough=5 -Wno-main -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-unused-const-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -g -gdwarf-4 -pg -mrecord-mcount -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wvla -Wno-pointer-sign -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-stringop-overflow -Wno-restrict -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -fno-strict-overflow -fno-stack-check -fconserve-stack -Werror=date-time -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types -Werror=designated-init -include /tmp/vbox.0/include/VBox/SUPDrvMangling.h -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-pie -Wno-declaration-after-statement -I./include -I/tmp/vbox.0/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DRT_WITHOUT_PRAGMA_ONCE -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_SUP_R0 -DVBOX -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBOX_WITH_HARDENING -DSUPDRV_WITH_RELEASE_LOGGER -DVBOX_WITHOUT_EFLAGS_AC_SET_IN_VBOXDRV -DIPRT_WITHOUT_EFLAGS_AC_PRESERVING -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS -DCONFIG_VBOXDRV_AS_MISC -DRT_ARCH_AMD64 -fsanitize=bounds -fsanitize-undefined-trap-on-error -DMODULE -DKBUILD_BASENAME='"alloc_r0drv"' -DKBUILD_MODNAME='"vboxdrv"' -D__KBUILD_MODNAME=kmod_vboxdrv -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/alloc-r0drv.o /tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/alloc-r0drv.c
scripts/basic/fixdep: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by scripts/basic/fixdep)
scripts/basic/fixdep: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by scripts/basic/fixdep)
scripts/Makefile.build:277: recipe for target '/tmp/vbox.0/SUPLibAll.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/tmp/vbox.0/SUPLibAll.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Deleting file '/tmp/vbox.0/SUPLibAll.o'
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
scripts/basic/fixdep: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by scripts/basic/fixdep)
scripts/basic/fixdep: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by scripts/basic/fixdep)
scripts/Makefile.build:277: recipe for target '/tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrvSem.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrvSem.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Deleting file '/tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrvSem.o'
scripts/basic/fixdep: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by scripts/basic/fixdep)
scripts/basic/fixdep: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by scripts/basic/fixdep)
scripts/Makefile.build:277: recipe for target '/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/initterm-r0drv.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/initterm-r0drv.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Deleting file '/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/initterm-r0drv.o'
scripts/basic/fixdep: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by scripts/basic/fixdep)
scripts/basic/fixdep: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by scripts/basic/fixdep)
scripts/Makefile.build:277: recipe for target '/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/alloc-r0drv.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/alloc-r0drv.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Deleting file '/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/alloc-r0drv.o'
scripts/basic/fixdep: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by scripts/basic/fixdep)
scripts/basic/fixdep: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by scripts/basic/fixdep)
scripts/Makefile.build:277: recipe for target '/tmp/vbox.0/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/tmp/vbox.0/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Deleting file '/tmp/vbox.0/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o'
scripts/basic/fixdep: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by scripts/basic/fixdep)
scripts/basic/fixdep: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by scripts/basic/fixdep)
scripts/Makefile.build:277: recipe for target '/tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrvTracer.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrvTracer.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Deleting file '/tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrvTracer.o'
scripts/basic/fixdep: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by scripts/basic/fixdep)
scripts/basic/fixdep: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by scripts/basic/fixdep)
scripts/Makefile.build:277: recipe for target '/tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrvGip.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrvGip.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Deleting file '/tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrvGip.o'
scripts/basic/fixdep: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by scripts/basic/fixdep)
scripts/basic/fixdep: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by scripts/basic/fixdep)
scripts/Makefile.build:277: recipe for target '/tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrv.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrv.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Deleting file '/tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrv.o'
Makefile:1874: recipe for target '/tmp/vbox.0' failed
make[1]: *** [/tmp/vbox.0] Error 2
/tmp/vbox.0/Makefile-footer.gmk:117: recipe for target 'vboxdrv' failed
make: *** [vboxdrv] Error 2
```

Then I ran it again, and I got a different error message:

```
This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel
for adding new hardware support to the system.
The distribution packages containing the headers are probably:
linux-headers-generic linux-headers-5.15.0-051500-generic
This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel
for adding new hardware support to the system.
The distribution packages containing the headers are probably:
linux-headers-generic linux-headers-5.15.0-051500-generic

There were problems setting up VirtualBox. To re-start the set-up process, run
/sbin/vboxconfig
as root. If your system is using EFI Secure Boot you may need to sign the
kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load
them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.
```

How can I solve this?

Regards!

**Edit**

I download the missing headers and when I try to install it by `dpg` I get this error:

```
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-5.15.0-051500-generic.
(Reading database ... 831861 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-5.15.0-051500-generic_5.15.0-051500.202110312130_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-5.15.0-051500-generic (5.15.0-051500.202110312130) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-5.15.0-051500-generic:
 linux-headers-5.15.0-051500-generic depends on libc6 (>= 2.34); however:
  Version of libc6:amd64 on system is 2.27-3ubuntu1.4.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-5.15.0-051500-generic (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-5.15.0-051500-generic
```

Why?

Comment: `version GLIBC_2.33 not found` - your system is broken. How and why it happened I've no idea. Reinstalling from scratch will most likely fix it unless you break it again.

Comment: Reinstalling the whole system? If yes, this is not possibile unfortunately.

Comment: I added some info about headers installation failure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle VirtualBox aims to support whatever was the newest released Linux kernel *at the time a particular version of VirtualBox was released*.

- Linux kernel 5.15.0 was released on 2021-10-31.
- VirtualBox 6.1.28 (the current version) was released on 2021-10-19.

Since kernel 5.15.0 *did not exist yet* when VirtualBox 6.1.28 was released, there are no guarantees that the VirtualBox drivers can be built successfully or work with kernel 5.15.0.

You're also using a kernel package built with a compiler version that is different from what your Mint 19.3 has. This may also cause problems when trying to build the VirtualBox drivers for your kernel.

For a third reason, the corresponding `linux-headers` package for your 5.15.0 kernel was obviously built for some other distribution, because it depends on a different version of `libc6`. Trying to update the distribution's default version of `libc6` with a third-party one is **very much not recommended** unless you really know what you are doing.

An error in `libc6` upgrade has the potential to "break everything": it can make effectively all dynamically linked executables (i.e. more than 99% of all executables) unusable.

If you need a newer `libc6` for whatever you're doing, you probably should update to a newer version of your Linux distribution instead. In other words, you should seriously think about updating to Mint 20.2 first instead of trying to bolt a bleeding-edge kernel and a newer `libc6` onto Mint 19.3.

And if you need VirtualBox, even with Mint 20.2, stick with kernel versions 5.14.x or less until the next maintenance release of VirtualBox (probably 6.1.30) comes out, unless you really want to participate in VirtualBox development.

You would first need to [upgrade from Mint 19.3 to 20](https://linuxmint-user-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/upgrade-to-mint-20.html), then [upgrade from Mint 20 to 20.2.](https://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=4111)

Comment: Thank you for your detail answer. I need kernel 5.15.0 because it integrated the newer Paragon NTFS3 driver. Do you think that this driver may be made available to older kernels?

Comment: It looks like you might be able to get the Paragon NTFS3 driver from [this Git repository](https://github.com/rmnscnce/ntfs3) and build it as a third-party module for kernel 5.14, but I wouldn't expect further backports to older versions unless a large enterprise distribution like RedHat or SuSE makes the effort to backport it further.

Comment: I did not install the 5.14 yet, but I suspect that it may have the same dependency issue with LIBC. :(

Comment: If you compile it yourself on your Mint 19.3 system, it should not have such a dependency issue; if you get a pre-packaged kernel intended for some other version of Mint or even for some other distribution, you're likely to run into dependency issues like that.

Comment: Great suggestion! Could you point me to a tutorial to compile the kernel on my own?

Comment: Here https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/compiling-linux-kernel-26.html is a good starting point for building a custom kernel. I will try it, then I will get you a feedback. Thank you so much.

Comment: Problem solved by compiling 5.15.1 on my own. Thank you.